# How to upload/download files to server with phonegap build

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I´m trying to downloads files from my server to device with phonegap build and ionic. I´m trying with cordovaFileTransfer, the APK generated is OK but when I try to install in device I get the error:

Unfortunatelly the App stops.

I´m using the theme IonFullApp for Ionic, can someone tell me how to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is trying to upload or download files to server with phonegap build (using IonFullApp theme) you need to change config.xml:

Add this two lines:

```
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" spec="0.4.8" source="pgb" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0"/>
```

Modify cordova-plugin-admobpro from

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-admobpro" spec="^2.8.3" />
```

to

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-admobpro" spec="2.7.7" />
```

Now you can create a controller to download a file from server to device like:

```
.controller('DocumentosCtrl', function($scope, $http, $ionicPopup) {

    $scope.testFileDownload = function() {
       var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
       var uri = encodeURI("http://s14.postimg.org/i8qvaxyup/bitcoin1.jpg");
         var filename = uri.split("/").pop();
       var fileURL = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + filename;
        alert(fileURL);
       fileTransfer.download(
          uri, fileURL, function(entry) {
                     alert(download complete: " + entry.toURL());
          },

          function(error) {alert("download error source ---" + JSON.stringify(error));
          },

          false, {
             headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
             }
          }
          )
};
```

})

Answer (score 0):

The cordova plugin `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` is [due to be deprecated](https://cordova.apache.org/blog/2017/10/18/from-filetransfer-to-xhr2.html) and its latest [npm version fails on iOS](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/issues/297).

Therefore these two working functions are purely based on JS, and thus no need to use extra plugins, besides the standard plugin `cordova-plugin-file`:

https://gist.github.com/jfoclpf/07e52f6bdf9c967449c4bc06af44c94a